# How can I set sublime as default text editor for crontab?

Tags: cron

How can I set sublime as default text editor for crontab?

I write cron jobs regularly so I would like to be able to edit crontab -e
using sublime rather than Nano.

I have started with creating a .desktop file for Sublime.

I have also tried to use select-editor from Terminal but it does not display Sublime as an option.

Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 8):

This is likely due to missing the `-w`/`--wait` flag which makes the command (`subl`) exit only *after* you close the file (the temporary cron file in this case). Without it, "cron" thinks you finished editing immediately as the command exits and any changes just ends up in the temporary file left for nothing.

So, one solution is:

Create a new file `sublime-wait`:

```
#!/bin/sh
subl -w $*
```

Add to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`:

```
export EDITOR='/path/to/sublime-wait'
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for me. Too bad there's no way to include small code snippets in comments, so I had to put them on another answer [below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1477045/809733).

Answer (score 5):

The sequence to pick the `editor` by `cron` is following, the first one wins:

- `VISUAL` environment variable
- `EDITOR` environment variable
- `/usr/bin/editor`

So set the `VISUAL` as sublime's path e.g.:

```
export VISUAL=/usr/bin/subl
```

Add this to your `~/.bashrc` for permanent assignment.

---

For just one run, send `VISUAL` to `crontab`'s environment:

```
VISUAL=/usr/bin/subl crontab -e
```

Comment: It works in the sense that it opens the crontab -e file in Sublime BUT I am not able to save the file.in Sublime (Unable to save). Can you fix that too?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the default editor in one of the above mentioned ways does work, e.g. editing the .bashrc file, exporting the variables EDITOR and VISUAL.
But - at least in my environment - crontab -e does not wait for the editor to close the updated file and terminates saying "No modification made".
Adding

```
export EDITOR="xed -w"
export VISUAL="xed -w"
```

solves the problem.

Comment: at least on macOS, spaces in the variable name are parsed as part of the file name and not an arg: `$ crontab -e 
crontab: xed -w: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@thomas-jensen answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1001011/809733), I'd like to suggest a small modification, in order to avoid trouble when there is no GUI available, and applying what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55093328/5136578):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ x$DISPLAY != x ] ; then
  # GUI Enabled
  /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -w $*
else
  vi $*
fi
```